# Do you need an @icloud.com email to get @icloud.com email aliases?

Tags: icloud, email

If you sign up for an Apple ID with a non-apple email account (gmail, etc.) can you still sign up for iCloud email aliases (alias@icloud.com)?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can. Set up the primary ID as your gmail and secondary as an iCloud account

Comment: Are you implying that the sign up process with a Gmail address will prompt the user if they would also like an iCloud email address?

Comment: I had made my account using my Outlook ID. I added another ID as my iCloud ID in the secondary ID